# cannot load such file -- coffee_script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going to remove active_admin from my angular rails app.
So I ran the following commands.

```
rails destroy active_admin:install
rails destroy active_admin:resource product
```

And I met this error.

```
cannot load such file -- coffee_script

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: It's useful to mention the rails and active_admin version.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. I solved the problem by just commenting it out and removing the scripts where it is causing the problems.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

or

try adding `"gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'"` to the Gemfile and running `bundle:install`.

> in rails > 5.2

we need to use  rake `rails tmp:cache:clear`

Answer (score 10):

It may be the cache. Try this: `rake tmp:cache:clear` and restart your server.

Answer (score 6):

## Clear Cache

Like the other answers say:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

## Do you have any coffee script files?

Likely, look in your assets/javascripts file: there may be some coffee script files in there. If you don't need them, then you can get can simply delete. Now try again and it should work.

## If you have coffee script files that you want to keep:

Then add the following to your gemfile and run `bundle install`

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
```

It should now work.

Comment: This was the answer for me. I upgraded from rails 6 to rails 7. I no longer need coffee_script files. I rm -r app/assets/javascript since my javascript is no located in app/javascript using esbuild.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, none of the solutions above worked for me.

Using rails 5.2.2, I added `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 5.0.0`

Then `bundle:install` and `rails tmp:cache:clear`

Finally, I've restarted the server and all worked fine.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone started the project without `--skip-coffee` flag but then remove coffee-rails gem later. This could result in the same error.

In that case try renaming all `*.coffee` or `*.js.coffee` to just `*.js`. Also, `rake tmp:cache:clear` and restart server